# Azure DevOps Multi Repo email Notification missing the commits from second repo

Tags: email, github, azure-devops

We created the Azure DevOps build pipeline with multi repo config as mentioned below and this works fine.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: project-source # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  jobs
    - job: CodeBuild
    displayName: Code Build

    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: project-source
```

We also have DevOps Notification configured on the build status, The Commits section of notification mail shows changes from  IAC repo(self) but not the source code repo(project-source).

Are we missing any configuration?
Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem on my side. The commit information from github is not displayed in the notification email. I think this could be a bug, you can report this problem on our [Develop Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem). After confirmation by our engineers, they will report this issue to the product team. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

[image]

[image]